# Querying scenario in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

as I'm new in mongoDB, I was wondering about the following problem: there is a field (lets call as `fieldA`) in my document. This field's value is stored as hexadecimal string of a numerical representation. Is it possible to retrieve the subset of those documents where `fieldA` value falls in a give range of values, based on the numerical representation? I'm assuming as that field is stored as a string, mongoDB would compare lexicographically `fieldA` according to the given query limits, what would be inconsistent to my needs.

Let's say my range of documents is: `fieldA >= "0x12f"` and `fieldA <= "0x12ea"` In this case I'm assuming mongoDB would compare lexicographically to make decisions, but in this case I would like to compare based on the numerical values.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Why not have a different field with the corresponding decimal number and use it for range queries?

Comment: @cjungel that would be a good solution yes. But I'm concerned about the fact this field's value increases so fast that might get in a point the decimal number representation is not able to handle it. And basically that was the reason that field was designed like that.  As I'm programming in Java I was considering Long as the numerical representation, but yes, concerned about this fact.

Comment: Both java and mongo support 64 bits integers. Are you required to support larger numbers? If this is enough for your domain you could take advantage of native indexes and perform efficient range queries. If you absolutely need larger numbers you could represent them as strings with a fixed length (with preceding 0's). That way you could represent arbitrarily large numbers an still be able to use native indexes to perform range queries given that alphanumeric string ordering would be correct in your case.

Answer (score 0):

In MongoDB it is possible to perform range queries over hexadecimal larger than 64 bits if you convert the hex string to binary data.  Java's BigInteger class allows for this.

Consider the following code to insert and query hexadecimal values as binary

```
private static void bigIntTest(MongoCollection<Document> bigIntCollection) {
    // BigInteger cannot parse 0x, so it must be stripped off
    // the "16" argument represent base 16 radix
    BigInteger floor = new BigInteger("0x12f".substring(2), 16);
    BigInteger ceiling = new BigInteger("0x12ea".substring(2), 16);
    BigInteger between = new BigInteger("0x555".substring(2), 16);
    // The toByteArray() method on BigInteger returns a byte array
    // Containing the two's-complement representation of this BigInteger.
    // MongoDB will store the byte array as a binary data field
    bigIntCollection.insertOne(new Document("value", floor.toByteArray()));
    bigIntCollection.insertOne(new Document("value", between.toByteArray()));
    bigIntCollection.insertOne(new Document("value", ceiling.toByteArray()));

    rangeQuery(bigIntCollection, floor, ceiling);
    // Test with values greater than Long.MAX_VALUE
    BigInteger newFloor = new BigInteger("8000000000000000", 16);
    BigInteger newBetween = new BigInteger("1dcd64ffffffffffe58250e3", 16);
    BigInteger newCeiling = new BigInteger("4563918244f3fffff538dcfb7617ffff", 16);
    List<Document> newDocuments = Arrays.asList(new Document[] { new Document("value", newFloor.toByteArray()),
            new Document("value", newBetween.toByteArray()), new Document("value", newCeiling.toByteArray()) });
    bigIntCollection.insertMany(newDocuments);
    rangeQuery(bigIntCollection, newFloor, newCeiling);
}

private static void rangeQuery(MongoCollection<Document> bigIntCollection, BigInteger floor, BigInteger ceiling) {
    Document range = new Document("$gt", floor.toByteArray());
    range.append("$lt", ceiling.toByteArray());
    Document filter = new Document("value", range);
    FindIterable<Document> find = bigIntCollection.find().filter(filter);
    find.iterator().forEachRemaining(new Consumer<Document>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(Document t) {
            byte[] data = ((Binary) t.get("value")).getData();
            System.out.println(new BigInteger(data).toString(16));
        }
    });
}
```

The second set of hex values exceed `Long.MAX_VALUE` and it still worked like a charm.  I would, however, recommend extensive testing prior to using this technique in production especially if negative numbers are possible and around overflow boundaries.  Full code may be found [here](https://gist.github.com/JaiHirsch/f9e8cd0e7e063a655230c74b0f417ab3)

This solution come with an additional warning.  With large binary values indexing may become expensive in regards to ram and performance.  Make sure you review the MongoDB [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/optimize-query-performance-with-indexes-and-projections) on this topic.